# Form submit on same page with parameters - GET Method

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<form action=\"index.php?m=".$mm."&y=".$y."\">
 <input type=\"submit\" value=\"<\">
</form>
```

The variables $mm and $y are initialized and have a value.
But I am only getting redirected to:

> index.php?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why is everything escaped? Is this echoed in PHP...your code makes no sense.

Comment: for a form submitting on same page, why not just remove the action="" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Submitting a form with `method="get"` (the default) will replace any query string in the action with one generated by the form data.

Store your `m` and `y` values in `<input type="hidden" …>` elements instead.

Answer (score -1):

That is because you need to echo the values of $mm and $y

```
<form action="index.php?m=<?php echo $mm;?>&y=<?php echo $y;?>">
    <input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```